# What is the meaning of "to go by the hours"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I have been looking at a website for booking a taxi with pickup at an airport, and I am puzzled by an option I have: there is a check box for an option labeled as *I would like to go by the hours*. [image: See screenshot:]

I do not understand what it means in this context: does it mean I can choose to pay the taxi on a hourly rate instead of a flat fee, or instead of paying on the number of kilometers of the ride ?

Comment: It corresponds to "louer ***à l'heure*** / ***à la journée*** etc" in French. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click the button on [a similar form I found](https://www.dial7.com/WebRes/?y), it brings up a choice of a number of hours, so my guess is that instead of charging you to go from one place to another place, you can reserve the car for a number of hours and it will take you multiple places. To "go by the hours" is not idiomatic.

What they probably meant was "I want to rent/reserve by the hour". For example,

> With Legends Limousine, you can reserve comfort and style **by the hour**. 
>   ([Source](http://www.legendslimousine.com/car-service/hourly/))

This means that you pay an hourly rate, or a fixed amount for each hour that you have the car service.